# JPA EntityManager limit number of concurrent operations on DB

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, entitymanager

I am using JPA framework to do some database operations.

First of all I make an `EntityManager` object and then I save the entity object for a specific table by using the code snippet

```
"entityManager.persist(specificEntity)"
```

And this persist operation is done from method with annotaion

```
"@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)"
```

I try to persist large number of data using a for loop in that method and all the data is persisted in one transaction.
Normally all this works fine, but when i try to persist lot of rows, i face issue and error

```
"Out of operation records in transaction coordinator (increase MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations)"
```

My DB supports approx 32,000 concurrent operations.
So is there any way in JPA framework to specify the max number of concurrent operations.

Comment: One way to handle this is using pagination.
Having another method with "Requires_New trancsaction". collecting some specific amouth of rows in my first method and then passing that object to second method and persisting the data. But this i have to handle manually in my code. i want to know if JPA framework has some way to handle this issue.

Comment: No you need to solve this issue, don't make it JPA's responsibility. You need to make sure not to go over your DBMS's limit. In other words: you probably need to batch and keep your transactions smaller.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you create your entities inside the loop and the EntityManagers FlushModeType is set to COMMIT which means that the EM waits for your commit of the transaction until even sending/inserting records to the database.

Even if you could put the EM max operations count value, having the AS handling the insert of tens of thousands of entities in one transaction (worst case: even writing the transaction data to flat files waiting for the commit) surely is not a great idea.

Either do some kind of batch processing for chunks, or at least start with having the records auto committed by the FlushModeType set to AUTO in this special case.